# add role/user to AWS service catalog portfolio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli, aws-service-catalog

I am looking forward to add a role to AWS service catalog portfolio. I am able to add it through console but I want to do it from AWS CLI.

I am not able to find any option in AWS, can someone please help if i can add role to portfolio from CLI

Comment: posted a solution with api documentation link, did it work for you?

Comment: Yes it works, Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you are looking for [AssociatePrincipalWithPortfolio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/servicecatalog/associate-principal-with-portfolio.html).

this option allows to add role to your portfolio

```
--principal-arn (string)

The ARN of the principal (IAM user, role, or group).
```

example command

```
aws servicecatalog associate-principal-with-portfolio \
    --portfolio-id port-2s6abcdefwdh4 \
    --principal-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/usertest \
    --principal-type IAM
```